# graph the data from a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, multidimensional-array, d3.js

This page needs to display a graph that reads the data from a CSV file.

I have been following a tutorial on [TheCodingTutorials](http://thecodingtutorials.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/using-csv-and-text-files-with-d3.html).

I'm also trying to follow the [Multi-Column Data](http://thecodingtutorials.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/using-multi-column-data-with-d3-part-2.html) tutorial so that i can add the name to the graph. This is where i'm getting lost, the tutorial make it sound easy but i just don't get it. Every time i try to edit the code it errors out.

It works perfectly if you only want to read a single column csv file.

However I want to read a multiple columns csv file.

Also if there is something that could make it better please let me know.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
    {
  d3.text("data2.csv", function(unparsedData)
  {
   var data = d3.csv.parseRows(unparsedData);

   //Create the SVG graph.
   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%");


   var dataEnter = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter();
   var graphHeight = 450;
   var barWidth = 20;
   var barSeparation = 10;
   var maxData = 105;
   var horizontalBarDistance = barWidth + barSeparation;
   var textYOffset = horizontalBarDistance / 2 - 12;
   var textXOffset = 20;
   var barHeightMultiplier = graphHeight / maxData;


   //Draw the bars.
   dataEnter.append("rect").attr("y", function(d, i)
   {
    return i * horizontalBarDistance;
   }).attr("x", function(d)
   {
    return 100;
   }).attr("height", function(d)
   {
    return barWidth;
   }).attr("width", function(d)
   {
    return d * barHeightMultiplier;
   });


   //Draw the text.
   dataEnter.append("text").text(function(d)
   {
    return d;
   }).attr("y", function(d, i)
   {
    return i * horizontalBarDistance + textXOffset;
   }).attr("x");
 });
 };
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="JavaScript:timedRefresh(10000);"> 
</body>
</html>
```

My CSV file now looks like this

```
names,data
john,78
brad,105
amber,103
james,2
dean,74
pat,45
matt,6
andrew,18
ashley,15
```

==================================================================================

**UPDATE**

==================================================================================

Thanks to all your help this is my updated code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

<script type="text/javascript" src=".\JavaScripts\d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='index2.html'},120000);

    d3.csv("./data/data.csv", function(data){

   //Create the SVG graph.
    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg").attr("width", "1800").attr("height", "600");

    var dataEnter = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter();
    var graphWidth = 800;
    var barWidth = 40;
    var barSeparation = 30;
    var maxData = 2;
    var horizontalBarDistance = barWidth + barSeparation;
    var textYOffset = 25;
    var barXOffset = 260;
    var barYOffset = 5;
    var numXOffset = 230;
    var barHeightMultiplier = graphWidth / maxData;
    var fontSize = "30px";

    var color = d3.scale.category10();


   //Draw the bars.
    dataEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color(i);})
    .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * horizontalBarDistance - barYOffset;})
    .attr("x", barXOffset)
    .attr("height", function(d){return barWidth;}) 
    .attr("width", function(d){return d.data * barHeightMultiplier;});


   //Draw the text.
    dataEnter.append("text")
    .text(function(d){return d.Name;})
    .attr("font-size", fontSize)
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * horizontalBarDistance + textYOffset;})
    .attr("x");

   //Draw the numbers.
    dataEnter.append("text")
    .text(function(d){return d.data;})
    .attr("font-size", fontSize)
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * horizontalBarDistance + textYOffset;})
    .attr("x", numXOffset);

     //Draw the Target bar
    dataEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * horizontalBarDistance;})
    .attr("x", barXOffset + graphWidth)
    .attr("height", 70) 
    .attr("width", 10);

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
#title {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20;
}
#graph {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:40;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="title">Graph 1</div>
<div id="graph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting.  Can you link to some running code?

Comment: When i say it errors out i mean, It just doesn't work. i'm thinking this is because i have no idea how to separate the columns. i just need to change the code so the data refers to the `number` column.  [The coding tutorials's](http://thecodingtutorials.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/using-multi-column-data-with-d3-part-2.html) example displays all the data in text format. i need to put it into an array for the graph to use.

Comment: I see. I posted an answer that will hopefully help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data contains a header row as its first row, you should be using `d3.csv.parse` instead of `d3.csv.parseRows`.  The [CSV documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) explains the differences.

The result of parsing will be something that looks like this:

```
[
    {"names": "john", "data": 78},
    {"names": "brad", "data": 105},
    ...
]
```

So, when you use this data to create your `rect` elements, you get an object bound to each rect.  Then when you use `selection.attr` or `selection.style` the `d` value you are passed will be the bound object.  This means you will need to reference the property you want, either as `d.names` or `d.data`.  Each column in the file will be a different property on the object (as shown above).

One other thing to consider is possibly replacing `d3.text` with `d3.csv` to retrieve the file and parse the data in one step.

Comment: OK i have change `d3.text` to `d3.csv`, `d3.csv.parseRows` to `d3.csv.parse`, and `data` to `d.data`. so why is it that i get this error... `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'charCodeAt'`....... just guessing but, would it be because i'm using d3.v3.mim.js not d3.v3.js??

Comment: You should read the documentation link I referenced.  If you use d3.csv you don't need to also call parseRows because the parsing happens automatically.  The call back gets passed an array of objects that you can use directly to create your rects.

Comment: Ok i see now. i was trying to parse already parse data... working like a charm now thanks.

Comment: Quick question you might know... I need to change the color of each bar. what the best way of doing it.

Comment: d3 has categorical color scales with built in palettes called category10, category20 and so on.  Or you can define your own ordinal scale with color codes in the range.

Comment: Sorry to keep doing this but, I'm in need of help again. If i add another column to the csv file, can i turn that data(it will only have one number in it) in to a var.

Comment: Sure, every column you add will be turned into an additional property on the resulting objects automatically. Have you tried it? Were there results you weren't expecting?

Comment: That's what I've been trying, with no luck. I replaced the maxData var with `.attr("width", function(d){return d.data * (graphWidth / d.Target);` in the drawing of the bars. but it just doesn't work properly. i think i'm doing this wrong.

Comment: I know the data read properly as i tested it with the draw text section. but when i use the above code it just errors. `width="Infinity"` and `width="NaN"`

Comment: Use Chrome dev tools to put a breakpoint on that line and check out what the value of all variables are at the time. If that doesn't do it, you're probably better off creating a new question specific to this problem so you can give all of the new context.

Comment: I worked out why it wasn't working. i have taken your advice to create a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564086/making-a-variable-from-a-csv-file) also. thanks for all your help so far.