# Making a variable from a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have worked out whats happening but not how to fix it, or even if its the best way of doing this (Unlikely).

I have made a graph that reads from a csv file, this part works real well. However as i don't want to touch the code after its finished. This is why I’m after the best/easiest way to take the data from a csv file, and turn it into a variable.

All the code is on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346496/java-graph-with-data-from-csv-file). I was discussing this matter with Scott Cameron and discovered the problem i was encountering.

Stupidly I put this code in thinking it would work. (d.avrNum is what i want to turn into a variable.)

```
dataEnter.append("rect")
.attr("fill",function(d,i){return color(i);})
.attr("y", function(d, i){return i * horizontalBarDistance - barYOffset;})
.attr("x", barXOffset)
.attr("height", function(d){return barWidth;}) 
.attr("width", function(d){return d.data * (graphWidth / d.varNum)});
```

The last line is were i need the variable number to be. I worked out, like d.data the d.varNum will be reading the next number. However there is only 1 number in d.varNum, so this doesn't work.

Because I want to keep using the 1 number, I need to make a variable out of d.varNum. If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

[Before asking question about the code please have a look at it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346496/java-graph-with-data-from-csv-file)

---

update

---

I have done some more looking around and found [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999971/read-csv-data-with-d3-csv)..
I have tried to make it work for me but i don't real understand this code.

This is what i got

```
var rawTarget = ["d.Target"];
var targetNum = rawTarget.slice(2,3,4,5);
```

Its acting like it doesn't see the array at all.

As i have said all i want is the first number (as there is only 1 number) to be used as a variable. It would be taking the place of maxData in [my graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346496/graph-the-data-from-a-csv-file), if i can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding what you're asking; if you want varNum to refer to the number of rectangles you're drawing, this code will work:

```
var varNum = data.length;
...
  .attr("width", function(d){return d.data * (graphWidth / varNum)});
```

Comment: OK let me break it down more. The data for the graph gets read from a **csv** file, and the graph display perfectly. The reason I want varNum as a variable is because, this graph is scalable. OK math time. If the graphs `width = 800px`, and `varNum = 2`. You would only need the data to = 2 for it to hit the end (a rectangle `800px` long). However if `varNum = 4`, the data will only get half way(a rectangle `400px` long). Does this make it easier to understand what I’m doing

Comment: All i need to know is how i can make the d.varNum into a variable. As the data in the varNum come from the same csv file.